# One-Dimensional Line-Segments/Ranges Intersection Test: Solution Name?

Tags: math, range

I've worked out a method to test if two one-dimensional line-segments/ranges.

So defining a range as:

```
[min, max]
```

Given two instances of range:

```
a = [min, max] 
b = [min, max]
```

I use the following to test if they intersect:

```
(a.max - b.min) * (b.max - a.min) >= 0.
```

I think this is a one-dimensional cross-product, so my question is:

Is this solution classified as a one-dimensional cross-product or something else?

Comment: The generalization of cross-products is the wedge product which produces the exterior algebra of a vector space. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about:

```
intersects = !((a.max < b.min) || (b.max < a.min))
```

That's faster (no multiply involved and a decent compiler will optimize the NOT away) and just as readable.

Comment: Nice solution Aaron, I agree it's clearer than my solution, I think I'll use this instead in my code :)

Comment: isn't this equivalent to `b.min <= a.max && a.min <= b.max` ?

Answer (score 1):

A one-dimensional cross product is merely `x*y` for `x` and `y` both real numbers. So I guess you could call this a one-dimensional cross product, but that's just a fancy name for a multiplication.

It's a cute trick, but I don't think it has any special consequence mathematically. Cross-products are all about vectors, not line segments.

Comment: Thanks Peter, yea I was just looking for a fancy name :)

Answer (score 0):

Or just simply code:

```py
def segments_intersect(x1, x2, y1, y2):
    return x2 >= y1 and y2 >= x1
```

[Source](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/08/15/intersection-of-1d-segments)